# mongodb fast tags query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have a very large collection ( more than 800k ) and I need to implement a query for auto-complete ( based on word beginnings only ) functionality based on tags. my documents look like this:

```
 {
    "_id": "theid",
    "somefield": "some value",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "abc tag1",
            "vote": 5
        },
        {
            "name": "hij tag2",
            "vote": 22
        },
        {
            "name": "abc tag3",
            "vote": 5
        },
        {
            "name": "hij tag4",
            "vote": 77
        }
    ]
}
```

if for example my query would be for all tags that start with "ab" and has a "somefield" that is "some value" the result would be "abc tag1","abc tag3" ( only names ).
I care about the speed of the queries much more than the speed of the inserts and updates.

I assume that the aggregation framework would be the right way to go here, but what would be the best pipeline and indexes for very fast querying  ?

the documents are not 'tag' documents they are documents representing a client object, they contain much more data fields that I left out for simplicity, each client has several tags and another field ( I changed its name so it wont be confused with the tags array ). I need to get a set without duplicates of all tags that a group of clients have.

Comment: I tried doing something similar last year, but with a much smaller database. I ended up having to use Solr as the amount of data grew.

Comment: can you post the query and indexes you tried ? did you use aggregation framework ?

Comment: Sorry, the code is long gone, but it was based on regular expressions on the tag field. It pre-dates the aggregation framework, but I'm not sure that would be the best approach anyway. In my experience the aggregation framework likes to read entire documents into memory, even if the $match could done using only an index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document structure doesn't make sense - I'm assuming `tags` is an array and not an object. Try queries like this

```
db.tags.find({ "somefield" : "some value", "tags.name" : /^abc/ })
```

with an index on `{ "maintag" : 1, "tags.name" : 1 }`. MongoDB optimizes left-anchored regex queries into range queries, which can be fulfilled efficiently using an index (see the [$regex docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)).

You can get just the tags from this document structure using an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.tags.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "somefield" : "some value", "tags.name" : /^abc/ } },
    { "$unwind" : "$tags" },
    { "$match" : { "tags.name" : /^abc/ } },
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "tag_name" : "$tags.name" } }
])
```

Index only helps for first $match, so same indexes for the pipeline as for the query.

Comment: you were right I had a mistake in my object, i fixed it. your query will return all the documents that fit the condition, I need only a list of tags that fit without duplicates. otherwise I will fetch allot of unnecessary data.

Comment: The $ positional operator can project out 1 matching tag. If you really need to return all tags then you have structured your documents inappropriately. The documents should be tags with the main tag denormalized into them, instead of a main tag document with its tags attached.

Comment: I guess I wasnt clear in my question, please see my edit. its not a tag document, its a client document with nested demoralized array of tags.

Comment: Same thing - queries return documents, not embedded objects. You should insert what you want your queries to return into the database. For rarer things, use aggregation. This might be a more rare query to do, so I updated the answer with how to get the tags using aggregation.

Comment: thanks this works, but would this scale for over 800k documents ? I need this for input autocomplete , in your opinion would it be fast enough ? should the index be on tags or tags.name ?

Comment: It should be on `tags.name` - forgot to fix it when I wrote `tags` instead of `tags.name` when I first wrote the answer before I tested it. I fixed this in the original answer. The only way to know is to try, but 800K is not very many documents so I'd think it'll work on standard hardware as long as you do simple prefix matches so that the regexes can be optimized.